# img CSS transitions break when adding anchor tags to it

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm new to HTML/CSS and am working on one of my first projects at the moment.

Initially, I had images with a simple hover transition done via CSS tied to them. When you hovered on them, they would go to an opacity value of 0.8, and when you stopped hovering over them, they would smoothly go back to 1.0. However, as I progressed with the website, I reached a point where I wanted to make these images clickable, so I added anchor tags wrapped around every img tag in the HTML. Instead of targeting 'img' in the CSS, I changed to 'a', thinking that it would be an easy change, but this promptly broke the animation, and now I am stuck trying to figure out what could be going wrong.

I am not sure exactly which parts of the code that could be relevant here, but I will submit the parts I think are relevant.

```
<div id="bottom">
       <a href="produktA.html">
       <img id="pc2" src="files/images/pc202.jpg" alt="Keyboard with a cup of coffee"></a>
       <a href="produktB.html">
       <img id="pc3" src="files/images/pc301.jpg" alt="Phone taking picture landscape"></a>
       <a href="produktC.html">
       <img id="pc4" src="files/images/pc4.jpg" alt="Phone taking picture profile"></a>
     </div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
#bottom{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    #bottom{ 
        width: 92%;
    }
}

#pc2{
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 33.05%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.2%;
}

#pc3{
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 33.05%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0.2%;
}

#pc4{
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 33.05%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
}

#bottom > a:hover{
    opacity:0.8; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); 
    transition:.5s;
}

#bottom > a:not(:hover){
    opacity:1; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    transition:.5s;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `#bottom > a:not(:hover)` to `#bottom > a:link` like so:

```html
    <style>
        #bottom > a:link {
            opacity:1; 
            filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
            transition:.5s;
        }
        
        #bottom > a:hover{
            opacity:0.8; 
            filter:alpha(opacity=80); 
            transition:.5s;
        }
    </style>
    
    <div id="bottom">
        <a href="#">
            <img id="pc2" src="https://placeimg.com/140/300/animals" alt="Keyboard with a cup of coffee"></a>
        <a href="#">
            <img id="pc3" src="https://placeimg.com/180/300/animals" alt="Phone taking picture landscape"></a>
        <a href="#">
            <img id="pc4" src="https://placeimg.com/140/300/animals" alt="Phone taking picture profile"></a>
    </div>
```

In general, when working with `a:hover` you need to use `a:link` as a counterpart to ensure things work as expected. `a:link` is the default i.e. normal state of a link.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to resolve the issue - but rather it's the same as before. One detail that I probably shouldn't have left out, is that the images are laid up like in your snippet (i.e. 3 of them next to each other), and that the animation works perfectly on the middle one (which in the code is "pc3"), but not at all on the left and right one.

If it's not too much of a trouble - here is a gif recording from my website that illustrates my issue further. https://i.gyazo.com/bbe1db5a229ae7779b8c6772a7ca6bea.mp4

Comment: Remove `float: left;` and `float: right;` and reduce the width of the first image by 1%. Problem solved!

Comment: Using this level of precision: `width: 33.05%;` is generally not a good idea because you can't really expect to get that level of precision. Round those things down and you'll be good to go. And this: `margin-left: 0.2%;` is a bit of an overkill also. Half a percent is OK and even .3% but .2% is stretching things too far. Just reduce the width of your images by half a percent or so and you'll be good to go without breaking things with floats.

Comment: The browser has to do a calculation for pixels i.e. your percentages will be converted into pixels by the browser. And that means: The browser will either round up or down to the nearest whole number of pixels. In your case, it ended up calculating more than 100% of available pixels (after rounding up/down) and had, therefore, to push the right image down. That's where you came up with the idea of using floats because you wanted to force the browser to behave. Am I right? :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot - this perfectly solved my problem! I had no idea floats could break stuff like that.

I also took notice of what you wrote about my precision - I have now revised my styling to use larger percentages :-)

As for using floats - It was actually the other way around. I simply went in there using floats to begin with (yes, I'm THAT inexperienced). I think using floats is what enabled me to use `width` in such a reckless manner to begin with. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: As one of the next steps, I recommend looking into learning flexbox. Because floats are "on the way out" nowadays. But take it one step at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately I'm only learning this via uni. Wouldn't be so bad, unless the course material wasn't written back around 2013/14 (it commonly refers to HTML5 as something "new"). As such - I get to learn about floats, and not flexbox. Oh well.

Will look into it!